# Is there a quote arguing for soul's existence similar to "I cannot believe that the difference between man and a watch lies in complexity alone."

Tags: reference-request, quote, souls

A friend remembers a quote that argues for the existence of the soul that is similar to "*I cannot believe that the difference between man and a watch lies in complexity alone*." We interpret this as saying there isn't a gradient from inanimate to animate that is based on complexity, thus we interpret it as an argument for a soul.

Googling alone comes up with nothing. Hobbes in the Leviathan compares humans to watches (saying they are similar). This made me think of Locke, who did believe in the soul. I also thought maybe it is a response to La Mettrie's L’Homme-machine, but I can't find anything obvious.

Note, the idea embedded in the quote does not seem obviously related to Paley's watchmaker's analogy since it is about a soul rather than God.

Anyone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: This type of argument is known as the [argument from personal incredulity fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_incredulity).

Comment: I presume it was in relation to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmaker_analogy Penrose argues a more targeted version of this in The Emperor's New Mind. I think your search phrase is too vague.